# Laravel multiple apps same server do queues conflict if same name?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, supervisord

We're currently running two laravel applications on the same dedicated server. Each application utilizes laravel's queueing system for background jobs and notifications. Each uses redis for the driver. Neither define any specific queues, they are both using the default. Our supervisor .conf is as follows:

```
[program:site-one-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/siteone.com/artisan queue:work --sleep=5 --tries=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=4
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/siteone.com/storage/logs/worker.log

[program:site-two-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/sitetwo.com/artisan queue:work --sleep=5 --tries=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=4
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/sitetwo.com/storage/logs/worker.log
```

Everything worked as expected before adding the configuration for the second site. After adding it, we were testing and noticed that when invoking an event on sitetwo.com that triggered a notification to be sent to the queue, that the email addresses which should have received the notifications did not, and instead they were sent to two email addresses that only exist within the database for siteone.com!

Everything seems to function as expected as long as only one of the above supervisor jobs is running.

Is there somehow a conflict between the two different applications using the same queue name for processing? Did I botch the supervisor config? Is there something else that I'm missing here?

Comment: Hey there. How did you solve this ? In my case, we have different environments of the same app on the server. So, even queue names are same. How can I solve this ?

Comment: We used different queue names for each application. If you have different environments of the same app on the same server (assuming prod, test, dev, etc) you could still use different queue names. For example: app_prod, app_test, app_dev, app_etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the class is all Laravel cares about when reading the queue. So if you have 2 sites dispatching the job `App\Jobs\CoolEmailSender`, then whichever application picks it up first is going to process it, regardless of which invoked it.

I can think of 2 things here:

1. Multiple redis-instances

or

2. unique queue names passed to `--queue`

Comment: At lest for redis it takes into account the APP_NAME as well. For example the redis KEY would be [APP_NAME]_database_queues:default or [APP_NAME]_database_queues:[queue name]

Answer (score 2):

I just changed APP_ENV and APP_NAME into .env file and it worked for me.

For Example:

- First  .env: APP_ENV=local APP_NAME = localapp
- Second .env: APP_ENV=staging APP_NAME=stagingapp

Comment: This should be the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe late but did you try to modify the queue config at config/queue.php

```
'redis' => [
    'driver' => 'redis',
    'connection' => 'default',
    'queue' => 'project1', // 'project2'...
    'retry_after' => 90,
    'block_for' => null,
],
```

run queue with `--queue=project1`

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This answer is for those who are having multiple domains, multiple apps, and one database.**

You can dispatch & listen to your job from multiple servers by specifying the queue name.

**App 1**

```
 dispatch((new Job($payload))->onQueue('app1'));

 php artisan queue:listen --queue=app1
```

**App 2**

```
 dispatch((new Job($payload))->onQueue('app2'));

 php artisan queue:listen --queue=app2
```

Comment: which job file will process these jobs which has no name but just payload?

Comment: Instead of Job you can mention your file name which is present inside job folder

Ex:         dispatch((new MailBroker($payload))->onQueue('backend'));